# Changing Jumbotron opacity and make it full width without affecting the font and button

Tags: jquery, html, css

would like to ask how to change Jumbotron opacity and make it full width without affecting the opacity of the font and the button?

```
.jumbotron-special{
    text-align: center;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: image-url('header-bg.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: none;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    // how to only make background-image-opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the background in another element and decrease the opacity only for that element:

```
.jumbotron-special {
   position: relative;
}
.jumbotron-special:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('header-bg.jpg'); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.3;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Somehow it didnt work, the jumbotron now does not have any background image. Could it be affected by some other code?

Answer (score 0):

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ak3b0f4/

Basically, have a parent element manage the page flow, make it relative, and create a child element for the background, and one for the content (order matters due to z-index, unless you manually change it). Then, have the children be absolutely positioned, and fill the entire parent.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="bg">
        I'm in the background.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Important stuff!</h1>
        <button>Yup.</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.jumbotron {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.jumbotron .bg {
    opacity: 0.10;
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }

.jumbotron .content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```