# Jumbotron background image not staying inside the Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Jumbotron with a background image and text on top of it. I needed the background image to have a low opacity (so that the text on top is readable), so am setting the background image on the "after" pseudo-element, as recommended by a few posts on that topic.

The issue is that the background image isn't staying within the bounds of the jumbotron div (the actual image is taller/wider than the jumbotron div, and I want the browser to just resize it to stay within the jumbotron div - instead the image is spilling over into the divs below).

Here's my CSS:

```
.jumbotron{
  background:transparent;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.jumbotron:after{
   background-image: url(/assets/home/jumbotron_background-14b85e94838f7e237a5318b85a67a43e1ff02276069f6e48148a58eb90767f48.jpg);
  content: "";
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I've tried both "cover" and "100% 100%" for background-size, and in both cases, the image still spills out into the divs beneath.

The related HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Headline Here</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center">Secondary Headline/ Value Prop</h3>
        <p class="text-center"> Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer-row"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <%= link_to 'Get Started!', signup_or_dashboard, class: 'btn btn-xl btn-primary' %>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because, you gave the `background-image` a wrong value.

[image: wrong code snapshot]

**Correct Syntax:**
`background-image: url('path to image');`

it works.

Comment: This is my raw .scss file - I'm using Rails, so due to the asset pipeline can't link directly to an image using 'url'. image-url compiles to the correct image location in the asset pipeline. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: now this looks like an actual problem! This may be due to Ruby not compiling your *SCSS* properly. What do you do in such issues?

Comment: What do you mean? The scss seems to be compiling properly, the compiled css:. 
  `background-image: url(/assets/home/jumbotron_background-14b85e94838f7e237a5318b85a67a43e1ff02276069f6e48148a58eb90767f48.jpg);`

Comment: Also, going to update the original question with the css instead of the scss to avoid future confusion

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, I got a working solution by adding a max-height property to the jumbotron:after pseudo-element (the same solution works if you put the background image on a separate div inside the jumbotron as well, instead of using :after). So:

```
.jumbotron:after{
  background-image: url('home/jumbotron_background.jpg');
  content: "";
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center center;
  max-height: 540px;
  opacity: 0.3;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking two closing `divs`, one for the `jumbotron`, and one for the container. That may be the reason why the test-center is being occupied by the `jumbotron`

Is the `position:absolute` necessary? IMO, the `:after` is not needed

Comment: They're there, somehow got edited out in the stack overflow code indentation, I'll update the code in my original question to make sure they show.

Comment: The :after is needed so that I can put an opacity on the image itself, but not the text on top of it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959757/changing-jumbotron-opacity-and-make-it-full-width-without-affecting-the-font-and for an example of why

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS

```
.jumbotron{  
  padding: 0;
}
.jumbotron img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.jumbotron .container {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Your modified HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img src="home/jumbotron_background.jpg" />
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
         <h1 class="text-center">Headline Here</h1>
         <h3 class="text-center">Secondary Headline/ Value Prop</h3>
         <p class="text-center"> Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta
  felis euismod semper.
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class="spacer-row"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
  <%= link_to 'Get Started!', signup_or_dashboard, class: 'btn btn-xl btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Same as before - the image is still coming out of the jumbotron div

Comment: can you share a fiddle link or screenshot so that it will be easy to understand the actual issue.

Comment: Here's a screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2K2KEyZVtWgQ1FLdkhTemw1Nm8/view?usp=sharing. As you can see from my original HTML, the jumbotron div ends right after the green "get started" button, yet the image is pushing down into the "heading" divs below